# Building python dict out of a single list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of items which has a length of 14:

```
html_doc = [u'Crabtree Conservation Area - Number 28',
u'Conservation Area',
u'Environment Agency Flood Risk Zone 3',
u'Flood Risk Zone 3',
u'Environment Agency Flood Risk Zone 2',
u'Flood Risk Zone 2',
u'Buildings Structures And Works Exceeding 90 Metres',
u'Aerodrome Safeguarding London Heathrow 1',
u'Controlled Parking Zone T',
u'Controlled Parking Zone T',
u'Flood Zone 3 Low Residual Risk',
u'Flood Zone 3 Low Residual Risk',
u"Embankment Residents' Association",
u"Embankment Residents' Assoc."]
```

each of the elements in the array should be paired together as "Name":"Constraint_type" meaning that the first and second element of the list are related.

I have this code which I don' think would work:

```
for i in xrange(len(html_doc)):
  dict.append("Name:" html_doc[i], "Constraint_Type": html_doc[i+1])
```

Any Idea on this?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the `"Name:` and `"Constraint_Type"` strings fit in within your dict. The items can't all repeat the same keys. Can you give an example of the output you'd expect for your input list (or the first four or six items from it, perhaps)?

Answer (score 3):

```
html_dict = dict(zip(html_doc[::2], html_doc[1::2]))
```

Comment: @tzman have you tested this code? seems not working in my end!

Comment: Worked fine for me. The dictionary gets created as `html_dict`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `iter` with `dict` and `zip` to pair and create key/value from every two elements:

```
it = iter(html_doc)

print(dict(zip(it,it)))
{u'Buildings Structures And Works Exceeding 90 Metres': u'Aerodrome Safeguarding London Heathrow 1', u'Flood Zone 3 Low Residual Risk': u'Flood Zone 3 Low Residual Risk', u"Embankment Residents' Association": u"Embankment Residents' Assoc.", u'Crabtree Conservation Area - Number 28': u'Conservation Area', u'Controlled Parking Zone T': u'Controlled Parking Zone T', u'Environment Agency Flood Risk Zone 3': u'Flood Risk Zone 3', u'Environment Agency Flood Risk Zone 2': u'Flood Risk Zone 2'}
```

If you slice the list you create two new lists.

Comment: it was totally expected that there was going to be somebody with a `zip` construction :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `step` parameter in `xrange`:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(html_doc), 2):
    dict[html_doc[i]] = html_doc[i+1]
```

`xrange` needs the `start` parameter if you use `step`. If you use step, `xrange` will generate `[start, start+step, start+2*step ... ]`

Comment: fwiw, `step` is not a named argument on `xrange`. `append` is not a method on a `dict` (and the line has a syntax error)

Comment: No I blindly copy-pasted OPs code... That's what you get for doing that.

Comment: step totally does exist though. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

Comment: Right. I only use it once every x months so every time I make this mistake.

Comment: Well, ideally you would make the mistake privately. Notice it there and then publicly post the correct thing. Instead of asking why you got a downvote, which usually means you posted something incorrect.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, at some point during the evening you just get a bit blind to these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a quite readable approach:

```
d = {}
while html_doc:
    d[html_doc.pop()] = html_doc.pop()
```

Giving:

```
>>> d
{u'Buildings Structures And Works Exceeding 90 Metres': u'Aerodrome Safeguarding London Heathrow 1',
 u'Controlled Parking Zone T': u'Controlled Parking Zone T',
 u'Crabtree Conservation Area - Number 28': u'Conservation Area',
 u"Embankment Residents' Association": u"Embankment Residents' Assoc.",
 u'Environment Agency Flood Risk Zone 2': u'Flood Risk Zone 2',
 u'Environment Agency Flood Risk Zone 3': u'Flood Risk Zone 3',
 u'Flood Zone 3 Low Residual Risk': u'Flood Zone 3 Low Residual Risk'}
```